# Complement 32 bit data

Tags: c

```
int a=1;

// a=1 in binary representation 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001

int b =~a; 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1110

printf("%d",b)
```

output = -2.

why output is -2

32 bits--  0-31.

31st bit is signed bit. signed bit = 0 if no is +ve, 1 if no is -ve.

Since 1 has moved to 31st bit . if signed bit is 1 is no -ve. Then why value 2

Is my understanding correct. If not guide me

Comment: It is implementation-defined how signed integers are represented. You cannot conclude from the standard what bitwise operations do to signed integers.

Comment: Read about [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). It's the most common way to handle signed numbers.

Comment: mixing **signed** integers with bitwise operations (the `~`) is usually a bad idea.

Answer (score 3):

How to compute the [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)?

First we *flip* all bits, then we add 1 to the result. Do this and you'll get 2, but since the MSB is 1, the result is negative:

`~00000001` is `11111110`, flip and you'll get `00000001`, now add 1: `00000010`

Answer (score 0):

negative numbers are build by bitwise negation and adding one

this is named twos complement.

if the ones complement would be used for representation of neg numbers then the zero would have two representations and it would complicate calculations. with twos complement you can simply use normal (at least the most) unsigned operations without caring if data is interpreted as signed or unsigned